# Why do Alphas fight when there's the possibility of passing the time reset power to a human?

Tags: plot-explanation, edge-of-tomorrow

Maybe I missed something when Rita and Dr. Carter explained things to Cage but if I remember correctly, they said the Red Mimics were common drones and are like claws, the Blue Mimics (Alphas) were the central nervous system and the Omega is the brain.

I'm wondering, other than using this for the plot of the movie, why does the alien even send out the blue Alphas out to fight and risk transferring the time resetting power to a human?  Wouldn't it be better to only use the Red Mimics to fight and not worry about transferring this power to a human who can then reset time?  What was the reason to have blue Alphas fighting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the source graphic novel, the Blue Mimics use this power to reset their own death and change their behaviour that causes it.  The transference is a freak accident.  If it was easy to replicate, the humans could have simply instructed the troops on how to transfer this power.  It's meant to be a one in a million (or two in a million, since it happened to Vrataski as well) long-shot, call it a "mistake" in the way Mimics operate.

Answer (score 2):

If you watch it again and listen carefully, they explain that the purpose of the Alphas fighting is specifically so if they get killed then their day resets. That's an Alpha power. Then the "queen" hive mind thing can choose a different tactic or strategy because the whole horde gets to live the day over. This is normally a huge advantage.

The other thing they say (quite quickly) in the movie is that taking the power from the alphas through their blood is something that they believe only humans can do. As in, the other planets conquered by the Mimics did not have species that could take the power from the alphas. So the mimics didn't know it could be a problem. It certainly seems like they figured it out, though, as the last alpha we see is very careful not to kill Cage.